# Feature Count in Legend (QGIS 2.18.2)

Tags: qgis, features, legend, count

Below is a screen shot of my Layers Panel showing two Graduated Category layers. One set of category features (Change in Small Firms (2015-2010)) are accompanied by counts, while the other (Change in Small Firm Counts (2015-2000)) is not. The counts for the first show up in the Composer output, but not in the second. I'd like both legends to be similar, but I can't figure out how to add or remove the counts.

[image: Layers Panel]

Comment: In the example shown for the feature counts, is there a way to select the sum of the points in each category of a different field other than the feature count shown? I have point counts in my layer, but the categorized data is from a different field in the same layer. i want to see how many points fall in a given percentage of categorized polygons.
Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may try a right click on your layer and then chose to *Show Feature Count* (green on figure):

[image: qgis menu]

Answer (score 5):

Right-click the entry in the layer list and activate **Show feature count**. (Can be heavy on big datasets but yours doesn't seem an issue.)

Answer (score 0):

To have more control on what you count and how you present the count (ie, to get rid of the brackets), use an aggregate expression in the appropriate legend label (+ `Insert or Edit an Expression`) and combine it with `concat()`. This one's to count features within the atlas geometry and also belonging to one category:

> ```
> concat('My count: ',
>   aggregate(layer:='A LAYER',
>     aggregate:='count',
>     expression:= A FIELD,
>     filter:= within($geometry, @atlas_geometry) AND "FIELD"=VALUE))
> ```

(Note that when closing the `Insert Expression` window, a `[%%]` will enclose your expression in the `Label` window.)